# How to let the app load with Default.png only when it is launched from scratch?

Tags: iphone

Example: My Default.png image shows the start screen of my app with an empty interface. When the app is launched from scratch the first time, this is cool. It appears like it started quickly. But when the user quits it and the app just goes to background, and then the user opens it, this sucks. Then I always end up with a wrong "snapshot" as launch image and my app then looks completely different after launch because it is like it was left the last time.

I would have to disable the Default.png when my app just goes to background, or I would have to enable it when it gets really terminated. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like your app isn't being suspended. Every app that I've used that supports fast-app switching hasn't shown its default png when I open it after suspending it.

Are you sure your app is supporting fast-app switching and that it is being suspended?

**Just updating my answer for some clarity that was revealed in the comments:**

In order to take advantage of fast-app switching, the following conditions need to be met:

- App needs to be compiled against the 4.0 SDK
- App needs to be running on a multitasking-capable device such as:

  - iPhone 4
  - iPhone 3GS
  - iPod touch 3rd Generation
- `info.plist` *must not* contain the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key.

Comment: If it's in the background, it will not show `Default.png` when it comes out of the background.  It will show the last state of the program (i.e. like minimizing/maximizing)

Comment: The multitasking model on iOS isn't true multitasking as you're used to with a desktop computer. When a user presses the home button the app is 'suspended'. Unless the app is specifically written to run background tasks, such as streaming audio, getting location updates or completing a long running task like a download, the app does not *run* when it's in the background.

Comment: To take advantage of fast-app switching, you need to compile your app against the 4.0 SDK, and be running on a multitasking-capable device. Such devices are iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS and iPod touch 3rd generation. I know it sounds patronising, but there are people who don't realise these points.

Comment: I'm compiling against 4.0 and run it on a 3 Gen iPod Touch. Probably the problem was that I forgot to remove the never-go-to-background-flag. roflmao.

Comment: If your app is always showing the `Default.png` then it does not have fast-app switching enabled (as Jasarien describes how to do above)