# Launch image for iPad app seems to incorrectly show for every screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uilaunchimagefile

I have set the launch image for my app to look like the initial screen. My app is a multi-screen/multi-view application that mostly takes place in a UINavigationController. But every screen can look very different, so there isn't really much commonality for a general launch image.

I have noticed that if I am in a screen in the app, then go out of the app (pressing the home button), then go back in, it shows the launch image, then it loads up the screen the user was last using. I think this is the expected behavior.

That being said, according to Apple, the launch image is required. So it seems that I have a few options:

1. Set an all black launch image
2. Cache an image of the last screen and somehow set that as a dynamic launch image
3. Specify to only use a launch image on the first screen
4. Don't specify launch image?

Right now I am leaning towards option 1 and just having an all-black launch image, but I would appreciate if anyone has any tips/suggestions/advice. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that the "launch" image (default.png) is shown even if the app was only in background (multitasking)?

Comment: If your app is multitasking this shouldn't be the case. Here is a similar question which may provide an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238746/how-to-let-the-app-load-with-default-png-only-when-it-is-launched-from-scratch And here is another, more recent question without an answer that is still quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309639/ipad-default-png-splashscreen-in-multitasking-mode

Comment: @Till yes, that is correct and what I appear to be observing.

Comment: @jwj in that case your app does not actually support multitasking (aka fast app switching) check the first answer from DavidBrainerBankers` links on details.

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker your second link appears to be exactly my same issue. There doesn't appear to be a resolution to it though, sadly.

Comment: @Till I agree with your hypothesis, however, I don't have that key defined (from the first link), and even tried adding it in and setting it to NO and still no avail. It's an iPad only app running in the iPad 5.0 simulator.

Comment: Just to throw a little more on here: thanks for the input from both of you. I have been reading up on some of the info from the links you provided and that has pointed me in the right direction. I haven't fixed the issue, however, I tried running my app in the 4.3 simulator and the screen transitions appear correct (i.e., the correct image is phasing in and out). So at the moment this seems to be a bug in 5.0.x. I also deployed the app to my iPad with iOS 5.0.1 and noticed the same behavior. I also noticed a few other posts on SO where people are describing the same problem.